# Is it possible use Xamarin Android Device Manager to create emulator with API below 19?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible use `Xamarin Android Device Manager` to create emulator with API below 19? I have choose `tag.id` to `google_apis`, but there is no image below API 19, even if they are intalled.

Comment: What is your VS version? My VS is 15.7.3, I can create a emulator 19.

Comment: I need create emulator with API 15

Comment: Please read [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/).  You can use Google’s emulator. "We recommend you use Google’s emulator when you can, "